# JAR file is not opening in another system that i use

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I created a jar file in my laptop and it runs fine in Command Prompt without trouble but when i use the same in my friend's laptop it shows and exception and the file does not run. But it's still good with my laptop. What's the reason?

I used the command

```
java jar filename.jar
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Just to make sure, the command should be `java -jar filename.jar`.

Comment: please post the exeption / error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one of the two possibilities:

1. On which version of JDK have you compiled your jar and what version of java is your friend having. (Maybe you use 1.7 to compile and friends using 1.6 to run)
2. Are you using any external dependencies in the jar, which is mentioned in MANIFEST.MF file, if yes, make sure their paths are correctly resolved.